# Reading from a oracle temp table in a separate procedure than the one it was populted in

Tags: .net, oracle, transactions

I have a 2 stored procedures, the first creates an oracle temp table and the second reads from it.
The temp table only has scope for that session.
I'm calling the procedures from .Net and the second procedure never returns any results. However if I use the same sprocs and parameters in SQL*Plus it works fine.

I've tried creating an Oracle Transaction object and had hoped I'd be able to read the tables in while still using the same transaction - trying to emulate an SQL Plus type of single connection environment.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: Just curious why you are creating a "temp" table with session scope. Why not define a Global Temporary Table?

Comment: @mrjoltcola  He means that the data in the temp table will only be available in the same session. All temporary tables in oracle are "global". However, "global" only means that the table definition is visible to all sessions. Any data that is inserted will be visible only from the session that inserted it.

Comment: Hi Marcel. I don't see how you can be sure of his intent unless you have information not posted in the question. I assume he meant what he wrote, which is "the first (procedure) creates an oracle temp table". I suggested a GTT just in case he is unaware of the feature, so he might look into it. Normally, we don't refer to inserting into a GTT as "creating it" so I take him literally.

Comment: @mrjoltcola: perhaps - but as soon as I read "the temp table only has scope for that session" and "second procedure never returns any results" and "works in SQL*Plus" it became pretty obvious he was working with a GTT.

Comment: OR ... he might be doing what many a programmer have done who were not aware of GTTs, create a literal temporary table. The assumption is if a user knows a feature well enough to use it, he knows the correct terminology to describe the feature. I prefer to help him by providing the information, just in case. I'm not making some bold assumption, I'm just reading what he said. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways to connect to Oracle from .Net, but in general I assume that at some point you're creating a Connection object and using that to generate commands, etc.  You need to re-use that Connection object between the two calls.  This may mean passing the Connection object around, or using some kind of singleton pattern to retrieve it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a stab. I though i was doing that but i'll have to make sure i'm not closing the connection between commands and re-opening it. - I guess that would invalidate passing the connection in the first place.
I'll post back later.

Answer (score 0):

Use PRESERVE ON COMMIT when creating your GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE, otherwise the table will be cleared after each commit.